# If I make several instances of a class in Javascript, does each function of each instance get its own space in memory like a variable would?

Tags: javascript, function, class, memory, instance

I want to make several instances of a class, if I do this, will each instance get its own individual copy of each function in the class, or does each instance just point to a singular copy of the functions in the class?
I've tried googling this and found some threads that said most languages don't, but I did find one thread that had people in the comments say this is possible in js, but didn't specify on what conditions.
Also, I am using this format to make classes if that helps:

```
class thing {

  constructor(){

  }

  someFunction(){

  }

}
```

Comment: What are you hoping it will help you achieve if it does/prevent you from achieving if it does not? What sort of memory needs do you think a function has? I ask because it seems like your query will ultimately actually be about something else

Comment: I am hoping to not use a ton of memory. I want to create a ton of instances of a class, and if the functions are duplicated for each instance, my project will be doo doo. If thats the case I could get around it but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3):

Try it out. Knowing the `===` operator is strict equality:

```js
class thing {
  someFunction(){
    return this.meep;
  }
}
const t1 = new thing();
const t2 = new thing();
console.log(t1.someFunction === t2.someFunction);
console.log(t1.someFunction === thing.prototype.someFunction);
```

In fact, from the second `true` you can also tell it's the same function as on `thing`'s [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

Comment: This means that the answer is "no", each instance does not use new memory for the class function.

Comment: The perfect way to demonstrate the reason!

Answer (score -1):

In Object-Oriented Programming, the class you created serves as a blueprint for all the instances (objects) created from that class. This means all the objects inherit the properties and functions(methods) defined in the class.

However, if an instance of a class overrides a class method by defining its own instance method, then the method defined in the class will be ignored during execution. In Javascript, this is achieved through prototype chain.

Read the details here https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain